# Creating a pdf invoice in rails/ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, pdf

I want to create an invoice in PDF format using rails/ruby.

So company header and the top, client information, and then line items with pricing and then a total at the bottom etc.

What do you guys advise?

Is it tricky to get the formatting correct so it prints out correctly?

Answer (score 5):

I recommend a gem called prawn:
http://prawn.majesticseacreature.com/

I've used it before and liked the results.

Answer (score 4):

There is this great alternative oo:

http://railscasts.com/episodes/220-pdfkit